# .htaccess redirect "site/download/post/" to "site/post/"

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Need some help here...

How can i permanently redirect with `.htaccess` this URL:

```
mysite.tdl/download/post-name/
```

to this URL:

```
mysite.tdl/post-name/#ert_pane1-5
```

---

Actually i would like to know how to redirect to this URL too:

```
mysite.tdl/post-name/
```

---

Its WordPress and Download Manager plugin related.

What im trying to do is avoid visitors to reach the package download pages, and be redirected to the actual post pages.

In other words, what i need is to eliminate the `/download/` from all URLs.

Thank you.

---

My actual .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/download/(.*) $1/$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The last line is the one in question. It possibly makes no sense because i was playing on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the leading /download/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, tried that but no success... I still able to access `mysite.tdl/download/post-name/`

Comment: Show us your .htaccess

Comment: This is strange... Your code works at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but is not working on my site...

Comment: i Figured it out. Your RewriteRule must be inserted right after `RewriteBase /` and before any other RewriteRule. The reason i really dont know.. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes. I had just seen your .htaccess, but was too late to write about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by adding the following to your .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /download/post-name/ /post-name/
```

Redirecting to an anchor (#) is not possible as this is a client side action. You could use Javascript for this.

Comment: Like i said, The post-name is generic.. It should be a variable or something... I tried that code but no success...